# Error in H2O h2o.stackedEnsemble: "Don't know how to determine the distribution for a multinomial classifier"

Tags: r, h2o, multinomial

I am trying to build a stacked ensemble using H2O in R. It has five base learners - Random Forest, XGBoost, GLM, GBM and Naive Bayes. It is a classification problem with three levels. The base learners ran successfully and returned accuracy values on a test dataset.

When the base learners are used in h2o.stackedEnsemble, below error is returned:

> Error: water.exceptions.H2OIllegalArgumentException: water.exceptions.H2OIllegalArgumentException: Don't know how to determine the distribution for a multinomial classifier.

Below is the code snippet for the stacked ensemble section:

```
ensemble <- h2o.stackedEnsemble(x = setdiff(colnames(trainPCA), 
                                    c(depVarsMulti,"weightage")), #Names of indep vars
                                y = depVarsMulti, #dep var
                                training_frame = trainPCA,
                                model_id = "123",
                                base_models = c(ModelOneRF@model_id, 
 ModelTwoXGBoost@model_id,ModelThreeGLM@model_id,ModelFourGBM@model_id,ModelFiveBayes@model_id),
                                metalearner_algorithm = "drf",
                                metalearner_nfolds = nfolds)
```

Additonal details:

1. I am able to build stacked ensemble models similar to the grid example given [here](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/stacked-ensembles.html)
2. H2O Version: "3.21.0.4359" | R Version: "3.4.1 (2017-06-30)"
3. The H2O cluster is a local one

EDIT(Aug 3, 2018):

As suggested by Darren, I am adding a script that reproduces the problem using an open dataset Cars93 (from package CARS)

```
#######################################################################
# Minimum reproducible example for Stackoverflow
#######################################################################

# R version: 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)
# H2O cluster version: 3.21.0.4376
#OS: Linux (Azure Data Science VM)

#Installing and loading necessary libraries
cat("\n Installing and loading necessary libraries \n")
libsNeeded <- c("dplyr", "data.table", "randomForest", "stringr","doParallel", "parallel", "doSNOW", "rlang", "nlme", "MASS", "survival", "stringi", "dummies", "missRanger","cluster", "e1071","xgboost","ranger", "caret")
if(length(setdiff(libsNeeded, rownames(installed.packages()))) > 0){
  install.packages(setdiff(libsNeeded, rownames(installed.packages())))
}
lapply(libsNeeded, require, character.only = T)

#Installing latest H2O if not done already:
# install.packages("h2o", type="source", repos=(c("http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/latest_stable_R")))
library(h2o)
#Starting an H2O cluster
h2o.init(max_mem_size = "23g")


library(CARS)
dataFrame <- Cars93

#Removing rows where Passengers = 8 or 7 or 2, as their occurence frequency is low and for demonstration purpose, want to avoid errors coming because of this reason
dataFrame <-  dataFrame[!(dataFrame$Passengers %in% c("2", "7", "8")),]

#Making the dependent variable as factor
dataFrame$Passengers <-  as.factor(dataFrame$Passengers)

#Defining the variables to be used in modeling
depVars <- "Passengers"
indepNumVars <- c("Price","MPG.highway","EngineSize","Horsepower")
indepFactVars <- c("AirBags","Type")

#Keeping only columns of interest
dataFrame <- dataFrame[,c(indepFactVars,indepNumVars,depVars)]

#Converting dependent variables into dummy variables:
dataFrame <- dummy.data.frame(dataFrame, names=colnames(dataFrame[,indepFactVars]), sep="_")
names(dataFrame) <- gsub(" ", "_", names(dataFrame))


#Creating the train and test datasets
trainIndex <- createDataPartition(dataFrame[,depVars], times = 1, p = 0.75)
trainingData <- dataFrame[trainIndex$Resample1,]
testingData <- dataFrame[-trainIndex$Resample1,]


# H2O Frames
train <- as.h2o(trainingData)
test <- as.h2o(testingData)

# Perform PCA
depData <- train[, depVars]


train <- train[, setdiff(names(train), c(depVars))]

pca_model <- h2o.prcomp(training_frame = train,
                        model_id = NULL,
                        ignore_const_cols = TRUE,
                        transform = "STANDARDIZE",
                        pca_method = "GramSVD",
                        k = 10,
                        max_iterations = 5000,
                        seed = -1,
                        score_each_iteration = TRUE,
                        use_all_factor_levels = FALSE,
                        compute_metrics = TRUE,
                        max_runtime_secs = 0,
                        impute_missing = T)

cum_prop <- pca_model@model$model_summary["Cumulative Proportion", ]

# print(cum_prop)

cum_prop_to_consider <- length(cum_prop[cum_prop < .95]) + 1

cat("\n\n Number of principal components that explain 95% variance = ",cum_prop_to_consider,"\n\n")

trainPCA <- h2o.predict(pca_model, train)
if(cum_prop_to_consider > ncol(trainPCA)){
  trainPCA <- trainPCA[, 1:(cum_prop_to_consider - 1)] 
}else{
  trainPCA <- trainPCA[, 1:cum_prop_to_consider]
}

# pca_data <- as.data.table(pca_data)
trainPCA[, depVars] <- depData[, depVars]

#Preparing the test data:
testPCA <- h2o.predict(pca_model,test)
if(cum_prop_to_consider > ncol(testPCA)){
  testPCA <- testPCA[, 1:(cum_prop_to_consider - 1)] 
}else{
  testPCA <- testPCA[, 1:cum_prop_to_consider]
}
testPCA[, depVars] <- test[, depVars]

# For binary classification, response should be a factor
trainPCA[,depVars] <- as.factor(trainPCA[,depVars])
testPCA[,depVars] <- as.factor(test[,depVars])

#Weights of the training data:
trainPCA$weightage <- ifelse(trainPCA[,depVars] == "5", 1, ifelse(trainPCA[,depVars] == "4", 2, ifelse(trainPCA[,depVars] == "6", 2,1)))

# Number of CV folds (to generate level-one data for stacking)
nfolds <- 5


####################################################################################################
# Stacked Ensemble modeling
####################################################################################################

modelIteration <- Sys.Date()
modelIteration <- gsub("-", "_", modelIteration)
i = "withInsp"

# Train & Cross-validate a RF
ModelOneRF <- h2o.randomForest(x = setdiff(colnames(trainPCA),depVars),
                               y = depVars,
                               training_frame = trainPCA,
                               ntrees = 15,
                               nfolds = nfolds,
                               fold_assignment = "Stratified",
                               max_depth = 30,
                               min_rows = 1,
                               mtries = 3,
                               keep_cross_validation_predictions = TRUE,
                               seed = 1,
                               # verbose = T,
                               weights_column = "weightage",
                               model_id = paste0(i,"_ModelOneRF_",modelIteration))
cat("\n\n Mean accuracy of Random Forest Model (on cross validation):",ModelOneRF@model$cross_validation_metrics_summary[1,1],"\n\n")
perf_RF <- h2o.performance(model = ModelOneRF, newdata = testPCA)
cat("\n\n Accuracy of Random Forest Model (on test data):",1 - perf_RF@metrics$mean_per_class_error,"\n\n")


# Train & Cross-validate a XGBoost
ModelTwoXGBoost <- h2o.xgboost(x = setdiff(colnames(trainPCA),depVars),
                               y = depVars,
                               training_frame = trainPCA,
                               nfolds = nfolds,
                               fold_assignment = "Stratified",
                               weights_column = "weightage",
                               ntrees = 15,
                               max_depth = 20,
                               min_rows = 1,
                               learn_rate = 0.1,
                               eta = 0.3,
                               keep_cross_validation_predictions = TRUE,
                               seed = 1,
                               # verbose = T,
                               model_id = paste0(i,"_ModelTwoXGBoost_",modelIteration))
cat("\n\n Mean accuracy of XGBoost Model (on cross validation):",ModelTwoXGBoost@model$cross_validation_metrics_summary[1,1],"\n\n")
perf_XGBoost <- h2o.performance(model = ModelTwoXGBoost, newdata = testPCA)
cat("\n\n Accuracy of XGBoost Model (on test data):",1 - perf_XGBoost@metrics$mean_per_class_error,"\n\n")

#Train and cross validate a Generalized Linear Model (GLM)
ModelThreeGLM <- h2o.glm(family= "multinomial",
                         x = setdiff(colnames(trainPCA),depVars),
                         y = depVars,
                         training_frame = trainPCA,
                         nfolds = nfolds,
                         fold_assignment = "Stratified",
                         weights_column = "weightage",
                         alpha = 0.0,
                         lambda_search = T,
                         standardize = T,
                         seed = 1,
                         # verbose = T,
                         model_id = paste0(i,"_ModelThreeGLM_",modelIteration),
                         keep_cross_validation_predictions = TRUE)

cat("\n\n Mean accuracy of GLM Model (on cross validation):",ModelThreeGLM@model$cross_validation_metrics_summary[1,1],"\n\n")
perf_GLM <- h2o.performance(model = ModelThreeGLM, newdata = testPCA)
cat("\n\n Accuracy of GLM Model (on test data):",1 - perf_GLM@metrics$mean_per_class_error,"\n\n")

#Train and cross validate a Gradient Boosting Machine (GBM)
ModelFourGBM <- h2o.gbm(x = setdiff(colnames(trainPCA),depVars),
                        y = depVars,
                        training_frame = trainPCA,
                        nfolds = nfolds,
                        fold_assignment = "Stratified",
                        weights_column = "weightage",
                        ntrees = 10,
                        max_depth = 20,
                        seed = 1,
                        learn_rate = 0.05,
                        learn_rate_annealing = 0.99,
                        # verbose = T,
                        keep_cross_validation_predictions = TRUE,
                        model_id = paste0(i,"_ModelFourGBM_",modelIteration))
cat("\n\n Mean accuracy of GBM Model (on cross validation):",ModelFourGBM@model$cross_validation_metrics_summary[1,1],"\n\n")
perf_GBM <- h2o.performance(model = ModelFourGBM, newdata = testPCA)
cat("\n\n Accuracy of GBM Model (on test data):",1 - perf_GBM@metrics$mean_per_class_error,"\n\n")

#Train and cross validate a NaÃ¯ve Bayes Model
ModelFiveBayes <- h2o.naiveBayes(x = setdiff(colnames(trainPCA),c(depVars,"weightage")),
                                 y = depVars,
                                 training_frame = trainPCA,
                                 nfolds = nfolds,
                                 fold_assignment = "Stratified",
                                 # weights_column = "weightage",
                                 seed = 1,
                                 # verbose = T,
                                 keep_cross_validation_predictions = TRUE,
                                 model_id = paste0(i,"_ModelFiveBayes_",modelIteration))

cat("\n\n Mean accuracy of Naive Bayes Model (on cross validation):",ModelFiveBayes@model$cross_validation_metrics_summary[1,1],"\n\n")
perf_Bayes <- h2o.performance(model = ModelFiveBayes, newdata = testPCA)
cat("\n\n Accuracy of Naive Bayes Model (on test data):",1 - perf_Bayes@metrics$mean_per_class_error,"\n\n")



# Train a stacked ensemble using the GBM and RF above
ensemble <- h2o.stackedEnsemble(x = setdiff(colnames(trainPCA),c(depVars,"weightage")),
                                y = depVars,
                                training_frame = trainPCA,
                                # model_id = paste0(i,"_ModelEnsemble_",modelIteration),
                                model_id = paste0(i,"_ModelEnsemble_2_",modelIteration),
                                base_models = c(ModelOneRF@model_id, ModelTwoXGBoost@model_id,ModelThreeGLM@model_id,ModelFourGBM@model_id,ModelFiveBayes@model_id),
                                metalearner_algorithm = "drf",
                                metalearner_nfolds = nfolds)
```

Comment: If you leave each of the 5 models out, one at a time, hopefully you can narrow down which of the 5 is triggering it?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I had tried that, I continued facing the same error. It does not appear to be an issue with any of the base models. Also, I have tested the base models on test data and they work

Comment: Must be the `metalearner_algorithm` of "drf" then. By the way `metalearner_nfolds` is not mentioned in the docs. But you might want to try experimenting with `metalearner_params`: http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/algo-params/metalearner_params.html

Comment: Metalearner_params is interesting, I has planned to try it soon. About the "drf", I had also thought if the error is with using random forest, so I had tested "gbm" and "auto", but the error persisted. Metalearner_nfolds is mentioned here http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/stacked-ensembles.html?highlight=metalearner_nfolds

Comment: Update: tried the same process with updated H2O package version "3.21.0.4375" (released one day ago), and continue to get the same error

Comment: It'd be great if you made a reproducible example (i.e. with example data. and showing making all the models). https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I have updated the post with a reproducible example. Let me know if I should edit anything. Thanks!

Comment: would it be possible to shorted your reproducible code so it doesn't depend on so many packages and only requires a few lines of code that represent the heart of the issue?

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a bug (I filed the bug report [here](https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-5814)).  It seems like the multinomial case is not working for either XGBoost or Naive Bayes (we are missing test coverage of these two cases).  If you run the code below which removes those two models, it works.  We will fix this ASAP.  Thanks.

```
ensemble <- h2o.stackedEnsemble(x = setdiff(colnames(trainPCA),c(depVars,"weightage")),
                                y = depVars,
                                training_frame = trainPCA,
                                base_models = c(ModelThreeGLM@model_id, ModelFourGBM@model_id, ModelOneRF@model_id),
                                metalearner_algorithm = "drf",
                                metalearner_nfolds = nfolds)
```

**EDIT:** The bug is [fixed and merged](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/pull/2714) into master.  It will be available in the [nightly release](https://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/master/latest.html) starting tonight (Aug 7, 2018) or the next fix release, 3.20.0.5 (released in the next few days).